# Circledsteps give error "option clash for xcolor"

Tags: color, incompatibility, circles, menukeys

Consider:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

in TeXLive 2017 (the standard distribution in Ubuntu 18.04 and derivatives) will fail with

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

and pressing `H` on the error we have:

```
? H
The package 'xcolor' has already been loaded with options:
  [table].
There has now been an attempt to load it with no options. 
[...]
```

what's happening? I supposed that loading a package with no options (as it is done into `circledsteps.sty`) should be always ok --- it will simply inherit the already-specified one.

Comment: I have no problem with this code. Is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: @Bernard you are right --- works ok on TeXLive 2019, not on TeXLive 2017 --- thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, [as noticed by Bernard in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano), update your distribution --- the snippet has no problem in TeXLive 2019.

Otherwise, the problem is that the package `menukeys` uses the `catoptions` package; that package changes the behavior of package loading.

A possible workaround was [mildly suggested in chat by David Carlisle](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53685426#53685426), and implemented by myself (so all the blame is mine):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}
% ugly and dangerous workaround. Based on https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53685426#53685426, all the blame @Rmano
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{catoptions}{%
    \expandafter\let\csname opt@xcolor.sty\endcsname\relax}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```